# getting chromebook file to move or contents to paste

Tags: chromebook

On a Chromebook (Dell Chromebook 11), using Vim, I saved a file to /home/user/filename.txt . How can I get that content anywhere else in the world?

- gmail attach a file does not let me go to /home/user
- copy with Ctrl-C within Vim does not result in my text being in the paste buffer

I *can* see file:///home/chronos/user/Downloads/ in a browser, so if I could save content to /home/chronos/user/Downloads from Vim, I could get text out, but I can't do that.

In sum, I'd like any way to get the content of filename.txt anywhere outside the machine (cut and paste available in a browser, moving the file, resaving to a thumb drive). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`file:///home/chronos/user/Downloads/` is literally the same Downloads folder. However, you can do that with terminal as well (if you're linux geek, this should be pretty simple)

Since you said you were using Vim, I assume that developer mode is on. In the shell, you can make use of mv linux command to move it to downloads.

```
mv /your/path/to/file.txt ~/Downloads/file.txt
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you greatly, but I'm actually using a Vim app, and have no command line (which, if I did, I'd know how to invoke mv). I can't get the built-in Files app to look at /home/user, either. From what I've read, going to developer mode would require letting the machine wipe all user information, defeating my purpose.

Comment: @user5225518 Well, chromium doesn't allow you to look inside your OS unless you have developer mode on. With vim only, you can somehow try to copy that file. Because without developer mode on, only directory you can access is Downloads which is quite boring.

Comment: (Thanks for your continued attention to my query.)